# Buttons don't appear

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Why are my `Button`s not appearing?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("window title")
frame = ttk.Frame(window)

btnTest = Button(frame, text = 'test').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
btnExit = Button(frame, text = 'exit', command = exit).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Off-topic: See accepted answer to the question [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) _before_ you encounter the other problem with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You created the buttons inside a frame, and you're placing them with the `grid()` geometry manager, that's fine. But you haven't placed the frame itself, try this:

```
frame = ttk.Frame(window)
frame.grid()
```

Actually, the frame is the widget that's not appearing.

Comment: thanks :)

(new to python and struggling)